# Get Related model fields in django template

Tags: python, django, model

I am trying to fetch products and I want images of the same also with the product in the Django template.

MODEL

```
class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(blank=True,null=False,max_length=100)
    
class ProductImage(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(to='products.Product', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='images', default=None)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/product_inmages', null=False, blank=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.product.title
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you pass a `QuerySet` of `Product`s as `products` to the template, you can work with:

```
{% for product in products %}
    {% for image in product.images.all %}
        <img src="{{ image.image.url }}">
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

You can boost efficiency by loading all the relevant `ProductImage`s in bulk in the template with:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def my_view(request):
    products = Product.objects.prefetch_related('images')
    return render(request, 'name-of-some-template.html', {'products': products})
```

Comment: I have implemented the same but getting error                                                                                             Exception Type:  AttributeError
Exception Value:  

Cannot find 'productimage_set' on Product object, 'productimage_set' is an invalid parameter to prefetch_related()

Comment: @NamanMalik: did you specify a `related_name=''..."` on the `ForeignKey`?

Comment: Yes                                                                                                                                                                   class ProductImage(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(to='products.Product', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None, related_name='images')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/product_images', null=False, blank=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.product.title

Comment: @NamanMalik: then it is `images`, not `productimage_set`. Please next time make your minimal working example *reproducible*.